# Telephone number is not displaying correctly in ajax control toolkit mask?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have the following telephone number 866-234-5678.

I have an asp textbox and I am applying the following mask:

```
 <cc2:MaskedEditExtender ID="maskPhone" 
                         runat="server" 
                         ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false"
                         AutoComplete="false" 
                         MaskType="None" 
                         Mask="(999)-999-9999" 
                         InputDirection="LeftToRight"
                         TargetControlID="txtPhone">
 </cc2:MaskedEditExtender>
```

When I load a page with the textbox, the telephone number displays like the following:

(662)-345-678_

Comment: I thought the question was quite obvious.  Why is the number displaying incorrectly?

Comment: @Edoode: There's a disconnect between the phone number set and the phone number displayed.

Comment: My bad, didn't miss the first '8' in the applied mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mask states 4 digits for the last group. The underscore '_' displayed is the PromptCharacter of the MaskedEditExtender.

Comment: I know, I am loading the number into the textbox programmitcally.  When I load 866-234-5678, it displays as (662)-345-678_ instead of (866)-234-5678.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the .Text property in the page_load, code behind, the value of the rendered `<INPUT` is set, and then the Mask Applied with Javascript after the page finishes rendering in the browser. Because the first character (the `8`) isn't part of the mask as that point, the javascript for the extender seems to overwrite it with the first parenthesis `(` of the mask. It's an odd behaviour but completely replicable.

If you change your code behind to

```
tbxPhone.Text = " 8662345678";
```

This seems to fix it as the padded space is the one that gets truncated but that's damn fugly. Probably best to log a ticket with the devs on CodePlex or take a stab at fixing the extender yourself if you feel up to it :)

Answer (score 0):

I, too, had this problem, only my (525) 234-5678 showed up as (_25) 234-5678.  Left-padding with an extra character before binding the value to the TextBox cleared it right up.  Silly...